# Compile and run a C program in Emacs

Tags: c, emacs

I can not find how to run a c program in the emacs terminal.  I can compile it with M-x cc filename.c and it works fine.  What is the command to run the program. M-x  (what do i type).

Answer (score 22):

A much better idea would be to use a Makefile

```
---- X Makefile X----
build:
        gcc -o exec_name input.c
run:
    ./exec_name
```

And then you can do <kbd>M-x compile</kbd>  and give command as <kbd>make build</kbd>  to compile the program and <kbd>M-x compile</kbd>  followed by  <kbd>make run</kbd>  to run the program.

Another way of running would be <kbd>M-x gdb</kbd>

Comment: Of course you would want to make the `run` target depend on the executable and probably not have a `build` target.  I used to use a setup like this.  We had `%:run`, `%:gdb`, `%:valgrind`, etc. targets that would build any of our executables and run (normally, under gdb, under valgrind).  It's very helpful especially if compiling takes a long time.

Answer (score 13):

`shell-command` is what you're after.

Ask Emacs about it:  <kbd>C-h f "shell-command"</kbd>.  It's bound to <kbd>M-!</kbd>

EDIT: clarify exact action required

Do this:

<kbd>M-! foo-program</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>

Where foo-program is the name of the compiled executable.

Comment: I looked and it wasn't helpful.

Comment: I would suggest that you probably need to read the documentation more carefully. event_jr's suggestion was quite reasonable.

Comment: I did read it.  I am very new to this.  I do not understand what half of it means.  I just need to know what to type to get my program to run

Comment: If you don't understand this much, I would suggest you are unlikely to figure out this one problem in isolation. You likely do not understand how to use Emacs, how to use the shell, etc., and a few paragraphs of information on Stack Overflow would be insufficient to help you. I can recommend some good books if you like, but you would have to start by telling us if you're using Unix or not.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. I tried the M-! foo.c but i get a no match. If you have a good source I can read to help me out with these basic problems I would be grateful. I have been using codeblocks or eclipse to write my programs so I never had to deal with this stuff.  I have also tried the M-x !./a.out  but get a no match

Comment: is `foo.c` your compiled executable?  That seems strange.

Comment: clay123 your directory in which you have created a programme is not same as the dir you have run emacs. that's why it can't find the ./a.out

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to run program directly in the shell with `M-x shell` or `M-x term` to open shell in buffer in first case and real shell in second. Then run your program `./myprog`

Answer (score 5):

While this might not be the most optimal method to do so, but this is a very quick way of viewing the *output* of a C program.

```
;; Run C programs directly from within emacs
(defun execute-c-program ()
  (interactive)
  (defvar foo)
  (setq foo (concat "gcc " (buffer-name) " && ./a.out" ))
  (shell-command foo))

(global-set-key [C-f1] 'execute-c-program)
```

Just put the following code into  your init file, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>F1</kbd> to see the output in the minibuffer.

Comment: That's will not work properly if the program takes input from `stdin`

Answer (score 3):

You can always use `compile` just like you would to build it.  This is nice if your program spits out messages that can be highlighted and jumped to like a compiler.  You could also write a short function like:

```lisp
(defun run-current-file ()
  "Runs the compilation of the current file.
Assumes it has the same name, but without an extension"
  (interactive)
  (compile (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name)))
```

so that you don't have type the file name all the time.  This has the added benefit that you can let bind `default-directory` if the build product is in another directory, and you can have more complicated name munging.  Of course you can change `compile` to `shell-command` etc. if you prefer that output.